# How to make sure that highcharts spline graphs stays between 0 and 1?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on a survey system in PHP and am using Highcharts for drawing graphs. How can I make sure that the graph area shows 0 at the bottom and 1 on the top?

Comment: SHARE OUR CODE. IT DEPEND ON THE VALUES YOU WANT TO DISPLAY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the yAxis [min](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis--min) and [max](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis--max) options.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I found it helpful.